# How to avoid two results of the same row in join

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have three tables actually on virturt mart table one is **orders, another is item & one is order_user_info**
to get the user first name i need to join **order_user_info** table

but when i join it shows the result info double, below i have mentioned the query & result please guide how can avoid double result

**FOR JOIN FIRST NAME I AM USING BELOW MENTIONED QUERY **

```
LEFT JOIN `urbanite_virtuemart_order_userinfos` as Uinfo ON Uinfo.virtuemart_order_id=i.virtuemart_order_id
```

**COMPLETE QUERY **

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS o.created_on AS intervals, CAST( i.`created_on` AS DATE ) AS created_on, Uinfo.`first_name`, o.`order_number`, SUM(DISTINCT i.product_item_price * product_quantity) as order_subtotal_netto, SUM(DISTINCT i.product_subtotal_with_tax) as order_subtotal_brutto, COUNT(DISTINCT i.virtuemart_order_id) as count_order_id, SUM(i.product_quantity) as product_quantity FROM `urbanite_virtuemart_order_items` as i 

LEFT JOIN `urbanite_virtuemart_orders` as o ON o.virtuemart_order_id=i.virtuemart_order_id 
LEFT JOIN `urbanite_virtuemart_order_userinfos` as Uinfo ON Uinfo.virtuemart_order_id=i.virtuemart_order_id AND Uinfo.created_on = i.created_on AND Uinfo.virtuemart_user_id = o.virtuemart_user_id
WHERE (`i`.`order_status` = "S") AND i.virtuemart_vendor_id = "63" AND DATE( o.created_on ) BETWEEN "2013-06-01 05:00:00" AND "2013-06-30 05:00:00" 

GROUP BY intervals
ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 0, 400
```

**result i am getting with out join like below**

`intervals |  Created_on | order_no | order_subtotalnetto | order_subtotalbruto  | count_order_id  |  product_quantity`

2013-06-12 09:47:16 |2013-06-12 | 43940624 | 200.00000 | 200.00000 | 1 | 2

**result i am getting with join for firstname like below**

`intervals |  Created_on | order_no | f_name | order_subtotalnetto | order_subtotalbruto  | count_order_id  |  product_quantity`

2013-06-12 09:47:16 |2013-06-12 | Fatin Bokhari | 43940624 | 200.00000 | 200.00000 | 1 | 4

**see in with out join for first name it show product_quantity = 2 but when i join it shows the value double, i tried distinct but cant go this way as it show the product quantity = 1 every time**

**Kindly need rescue!**

Comment: Please use **bold** fonts more sparingly...

Comment: It would help if you could provide an sqlfiddle with your database schema on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: If you have an extra join for the firstname you can drop that and use a subselect instead. something like

    select a.*, (select b.name from table_b b where b.refid = a.id) as name
    from table_a a

Comment: thanks @RubenVerschueren your comment was helpful for me

Comment: thanks @MicKri too now i caught the issue actually when i was creating scheme on sqlfiddle thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

oh actually the rows comes twice in a **urbanite_virtuemart_order_userinfos** table so i used where clause & it works

```
WHERE (`i`.`order_status` = "S") AND i.virtuemart_vendor_id = "63" AND DATE( o.created_on ) BETWEEN "2013-06-01 05:00:00" AND "2013-06-30 05:00:00" AND Uinfo.`address_type` = 'BT'
```